# PHP Zend Framework Generator

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am in the phase of learning Zend Framework for PHP development, I have been doing 'dirty' PHP programming for about 2 years now and I have learnt quite a bit from my mistakes.

I have been introduced to Ruby On Rails, it is a great framework and Ruby is quite an interesting language too, but not everyone wants their web sites to be in RoR, at least not all of my clients.

Hence as a result I do a lot of PHP. Having worked on RoR, I find Zend Framework to provide very similar functionality and environment and hence I am really excited about the same.

However I am interested to know if there are any 'generator' scripts that help you along the process to generate / automate common tasks such as project structure creation, model creation, controller creation, just like those in RoR?

If such a thing already exists, great, otherwise I will go ahead and build such scripts myself as I am very certain they will come in very handy, especially for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Zend Tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.html) is your friend!

Comment: hm... documentation of that tool was pretty thin =/

Answer (score 2):

i have made several code snippets and file types in editor ( netbeans ) to help me with automation.
You could look into zend studio that has a built in integration for zend framework that work quite well, but its commercial and would mean switching IDE's wich is always a burdain

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a code generator for Zend Framework that could be useful to you. It is based off of the Qcubed code generator. Check it out at http://clintberry.com/2010/08/zend-framework-code-generator-with-scaffolding/

Answer (score 1):

This is the best tutorial I found. It explains how to start using Zend Framework step-by-step
[Zend Framework Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch/)